# Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder" -- Which classpath?

Tags: slf4j

My `pom.xml` contains only one reference to SLF4J:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.10</version>
    </dependency>
```

I am getting this error:

> SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
>
> SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation SLF4J:
>
> See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further
>   details.

I checked that URL and indeed it provides a solution: *"Placing one (and only one) of slf4j-nop.jar, slf4j-simple.jar, slf4j-log4j12.jar, slf4j-jdk14.jar or logback-classic.jar on **the class path** should solve the problem. "*

My question is: **which** classpath?

- The system's [%CLASSPATH%](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html)? (I don't have one! I will need to create it specifically for this)
- Eclipse's project `.classpath`? (I think I tried this but it didn't help)
- Other?

I found quite [a few](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9919375/1864054) postings on the subject [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11916706/slf4j-failed-to-load-class-org-slf4j-impl-staticloggerbinder-error) on SO, but they all quote the same answer: *"place ... on **the class path**"*.

**Which** classpath?

Comment: Are you using maven with Eclipse.?

Comment: @KonstantinosMargaritis Yes, I am using Maven with Eclipse: `1.` Eclipse 3.7.2 `2.` Maven 2.2.1 `3.` m2e plugin 1.2.0.20120903-1050. Any idea how to resolve this error *without* defaulting to the no-operation (NOP) logger implementation SLF4J? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using logback or something else. I am asking in order to tell you about the dependencies.

Comment: @KonstantinosMargaritis What is "logback"? How can I check if I am using it?

Comment: Logback is an implementation that can be used with slf4j. If you dont know it, it means you are not using it. I suggest you take a look at my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12382897/optional-printing-of-stack-trace-in-java/12389287#12389287 about logback and slf4j. My answer contains also classpath settings but you dont need that.

Comment: @KonstantinosMargaritis I inherited this system so it would've been quite possible that I was using it unbeknownst to me. But searching through `pom.xml` didn't yield any reference to 'logback'. It found one reference only to 'slf4j' (which is what's recommended). I will continue my comment in reply to your excellent answer below. Thanks.

Comment: I did not know that Daniel. I did not tell it in a bad way. It is easy to find out if you have it. In case you dont have any logback dependency that means you are not using it. As i see you have slf4j-jdk14 dependency so you can add the last dependency of it in your pom.xml. The last version is  <version>1.6.6</version>

Comment: For those like me who are new to build tools like maven or gradle, I found out that when someone says "add to classpath" they mean that you should add a dependency to your pom.xml or build.gradle files. I solved this issue by upgrading the version of the slf4j-simple dependency I was using.

Comment: The runtime jvm classpath...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

First of all in order to add SLF4J you should put **ONE** and only **ONE** of these dependencies in your pom.xml. It depends on what implementation you choose to use. Every dependency you add in the pom.xml is added automatically in the classpath. As long as you are using Eclipse there is no need to modify the system's %CLASSPATH%?

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
   <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
   <version></version>
</dependency>
```

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
   <version></version>
   <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
   <version></version>
   <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
   <version></version>
   <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Last but not least you will have the error SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".

Eclipse Juno and Indigo, when using the bundled maven version(m2e), are not suppressing the message SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder". This behaviour is present from the m2e version 1.1.0.20120530-0009 and onwards.

Although, this is indicated as an error your logs will be saved normally. The highlighted error will still be present until there is a fix of this bug. More about this in the [m2e support site](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=387064).

The current available solution in order to suppress this message is to use an external maven version rather than the bundled version of Eclipse. You can find about this solution and more details regarding this bug in the question below.

[SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder". error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11916706/slf4j-failed-to-load-class-org-slf4j-impl-staticloggerbinder-error)

Comment: Thanks for this excellent answer. First, it answers my question *"which classpath?"* (no need to follow m2e's support site suggestion because `slf4j-jdk14` is already referenced in the `pom.xml`?). Second, step #3 in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12373375/1864054) (link you provided) got rid of the error message: `Window` > `Preferences` > `Maven` > `Installations` > Uncheck `Embedded` > Add... `External`.

Comment: @Daniel You are more than welcome.! If you need any other assist with maven or logging let me know.

Comment: A short description of the different logging frameworks can be found here: http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html#swapping

Comment: @KonstantinosMargaritis, you saved my day ! Thank you. You gave a good explanation

Answer (score 0):

### Problem:

I'm using `Maven` to manage my dependencies. In my case, the reason I was getting this error was **because I had more than one `slf4j-simple` jar** in my system on my class path. The [SLF4J documentation](https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder) states:

> Placing one **(and only one)** of slf4j-nop.jar slf4j-simple.jar, slf4j-log4j12.jar, slf4j-jdk14.jar or logback-classic.jar on the class path should solve the problem.

### Solution:

- Search for the following jars in your file system and remove all copies other than the one in `.m3`:

  1. slf4j-nop
  2. slf4j-simple
  3. slf4j-log4j12
  4. slf4j-jdk14
  5. logback-classic

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `gradle` than add following dependency in build.gradle.kts

```
 dependencies {
    implementation("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.11")         
 }
```